# Is it possible to access .Net runtime via dll only

Tags: python, .net

I am using a PC (Win7) that is void of any MS development tools. However, python 2.7 is installed on this PC. ctype module is available in this installation. (It is not IronPython. It is just plain CPython)

Now if we look at Objective-C on osx, it is possible for a C program to access the Objective-C runtime by calling `objc_msgSend`   and a handful of other APIs (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html). It is a lot of pain and not recommended at all, but at least it is doable.

So given the constraints above (win7, no VStudio, python+ctype), is it possible for me to access the .Net runtime in a manner similar to objective-c?

Comment: If all you need to do is to access somehow the .NET runtime, keep in mind that if the .NET Framework is installed (even without VS or the .NET SDK) the C# compiler should be installed by default, look for `csc.exe` under `%windir%\Microsoft .NET\<version>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it possible for me to access the .Net runtime in a manner similar to objective-c?

The [.NET Runtime can be Hosted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380850.aspx), which allows you to access and use types directly from a native API.

That being said, there is often a simpler way to accomplish this.  If the .NET type(s) you need to access are COM visible, for example, you can just directly use them via COM.